# Understanding error from ld "archive member is not mach-o or llvm bitcode file"

Tags: macos, linker, fortran, macports

I'm getting the following error when trying to link a code on a Mac (Montery).  First let me say that up until a recent upgrade to Xcode the code built fine.  GCC is 10, OpenMPI and it's a Fortran code.  Now there are multiple executables which build and one libaray.  The library compiles fine and is archived via ar (`ar -ruvs`).  For example, here's a compile and build line for a code.

```
mpif90 -O2 -g -fexternal-blas -fbacktrace -fcheck=all,no-array-temps -fallow-argument-mismatch -I../../LIBSTELL/Release -I/opt/local/include -I. -c ../Sources/boozer_coords.f
mpif90 -shared  -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -O2 -g -fexternal-blas -fbacktrace -fcheck=all,no-array-temps -fallow-argument-mismatch -I../../LIBSTELL/Release -I/opt/local/include -o  xbooz_xform booz_jac.o read_wout_booz.o foranl.o allocate_boozer.o transpmn.o boozer_xform.o setup_booz.o write_boozmn.o harfun.o trigfunc.o booz_params.o vcoords.o boozer.o free_mem_boozer.o boozer_coords.o booz_persistent.o ../../LIBSTELL/Release/libstell.a -L/usr/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lopenblas -lscalapack -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdff -L/opt/local/lib -lfftw3 -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5hl_fortran -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5 -lz -ldl -lm
```

This works fine and produces an executable.  However, there is another code which links to this code.  For that reason archives are made of the compiled code.

```
mpif90 -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -ffixed-line-length-none  -O2 -g -fexternal-blas -fbacktrace -fcheck=all,no-array-temps -fallow-argument-mismatch -I../../LIBSTELL/Release -I../../BOOTSJ/Release  -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I. -c ../Sources/thrift_main.f90
mpif90 -shared  -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -O2 -g -fexternal-blas -fbacktrace -fcheck=all,no-array-temps -fallow-argument-mismatch -I../../LIBSTELL/Release -I/opt/local/include -o  xthrift thrift_interface_mod.o thrift_runtime.o thrift_main.o ../../BOOTSJ/Release/libbootsj.a ../../LIBSTELL/Release/libstell.a -L/usr/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lopenblas -lscalapack -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdff -L/opt/local/lib -lfftw3 -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5hl_fortran -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5 -lz -ldl -lm
ld: in ../../BOOTSJ/Release/libbootsj.a(parambs.mod), archive member 'parambs.mod' with length 2800 is not mach-o or llvm bitcode file '../../BOOTSJ/Release/libbootsj.a' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've had limited success trying to understand the source of this error.  Here's what the table for the archive looks like.

```
ar -t ../BOOTSJ/Release/libbootsj.a 
__.SYMDEF SORTED
SIMPUN.o
al31.o
allocate_angles.o
allocate_radial.o
bongrid.o
bootsj.o
caprsh2.o
datain.o
deallocate_all.o
denmf.o
do_fft.o
driver.o
fraction.o
grad.o
othersums.o
output.o
parambs.o
positiv.o
read_boozer.o
reorganz.o
smooth1.o
sumit.o
temp.o
tok_fraction.o
trig.o
vmec0.o
woflam.o
parambs.mod
trig.mod
vmec0.mod
```

Comment: The linker is telling you the problem.  This .mod file is not a mach-o file.  What do you expect the linker to do with it?  What is it?

Comment: Well the sources for the archive and the main code are all compiled with the same compiler on the same machine.  So I'd assume everything is still the same.  What more, the compiled files in the archive can be linked just fine when not in an archive.  Also the same code compiled with the Intel compiler works just fine.

Comment: I tried removing the .mod files from the archive.  This seems to clear up the error but it's odd that this only showed up after the latest updates to Xcode.

Comment: This could be the same problem as described here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444892/xcode-15-0-1-macos-sonoma-clang-archive-or-linking-issue

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was adding the module files (.mod) to the archive.  This was incorrect.  Only the Object (.o) files should be in the archive.

If I understand correctly the compiler will use the `-I <path>` command to look for (.mod) files.  So the archive only needs the object files.