# Xcode 15.0.1, macOS Sonoma: Clang archive or linking issue

Tags: macos, makefile, clang, ld, macos-sonoma

I have issues building my project on C, and I have created minimal build to reproduce the issue. Project build and use .a library, the error:

```
linker-test$ make
gcc -Wall -g -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -g -c -o ar-test1.o ar-test1.c
gcc -Wall -g -c -o ar-test2.o ar-test2.c
ar rcs libartest.a ar-test1.o ar-test2.o
gcc -Wall -g -o myapp main.o -L. -lartest
ld: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/serg/temp/temp/linker-test/libartest.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [myapp] Error 1
```

Archive to try: https://file.io/OomLs7yTSAnz

I find that some projects on github have issues with building after upgrade to sonoma with the same error, is there anyone who solved the problem?

#### Files:

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

# List of source files and object files
SRCS = main.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Archive name
LIBRARY = libartest.a

all: myapp

myapp: $(OBJS) $(LIBRARY)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) -L. -lartest

$(LIBRARY): ar-test1.o ar-test2.o
    ar rcs $(LIBRARY) ar-test1.o ar-test2.o

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f myapp $(OBJS) $(LIBRARY) *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

ar-test1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ar_test1() {
    printf("This is ar-test1.c\n");
}
```

ar-test2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ar_test2() {
    printf("This is ar-test2.c\n");
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue in some random instances like installing a Ruby gem that builds some native extensions. But I can't reproduce the issue on a different M1 system...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the used `ar` was installed from homebrew:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/binutils/bin/ar -V
GNU ar (GNU Binutils) 2.41
```

It worked on Ventura, but does not for Sonoma, tested with `Apple clang version 15.0.0` and `Homebrew clang version 17.0.6`.

Using `ar` from `/usr/bin/ar` solves the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue with CMake project (cmake+clion). With built-in clang it works well. But I don't know how to configure environment properly. `which ar` shows /usr/bin/ar but seems that CLion somewhere overrides it.

Comment: Update: adding an empty dummy function to all libraries fixed the issue. Seems that there should be at least one symbol.