# linking error during compilation with exit code 1 while downloading ruby. How can I solve this?

Tags: compiler-errors

I try to install Ruby by using ruby-install ruby 3.2.2.. I constantly get an error

```
compiling ripper.c
ripper.c:10310:9: warning: variable 'yynerrs' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int yynerrs = 0;
        ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
installing default ripper libraries
checking ../.././parse.y and ../.././ext/ripper/eventids2.c
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2/ext/ripper'
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2/ext/rubyvm'
installing default libraries
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2/ext/rubyvm'
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2/.bundle/gems/debug-1.7.1/ext/debug'
compiling debug.c
compiling iseq_collector.c
linking shared-object debug/debug.bundle
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2/.bundle/gems/debug-1.7.1/ext/debug'
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2'
config.status: creating ruby-runner.h
revision.h unchanged
linking ruby
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-ldl', '-lgmp', '-lobjc', '-lpthread'
ld: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Users/minseoksong/src/ruby-3.2.2/libruby.3.2-static.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I address this problem? Similar problem (linker fails with exit code 1) happened before when I tried to download other files in the past but I don't know what I should do to solve it. I'm sure this is not a problem about the code

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow related to a wrong `ar` version being used.

For me `brew remove binutils` resolved the issue.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444892/xcode-15-0-1-macos-sonoma-clang-archive-or-linking-issue).